# BaseからAccessに接続

Tags: ms-access, odbc, libreoffice

古いMicrosoft Access32ビット版の.mdbを使っています。

Libreoffice Base(x86_64版）に移行できないものかと思い、Baseの「既存のデーターベースに接続」から、Accessの.mdbを選んで接続してみましたが
「接続を作成できませんでした。必要なデータプロバイダーがインストールされていない可能性があります。」とのエラーになります。

ODBCの登録などをすれば、接続できるものなのでしょうか？
よろしく、お願い致します。

Comment: この記事が参考になるかも。[LibreOffice(バージョン6.0.6) BaseにAcces](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q13195071793) Access用の64bitODBCドライバを入れてみるとか。

Comment: 残念ながら、教えていただいた、方法では解決できませんでした。

Comment: ダメでしたか。それで検索し直してみました。またダメかもですが調べてみてください。まとめ記事 [ODBC components needed in Win10 x64 OS. Where available?](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/152745/), およびそれからのリンク https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/Faq/Base/How_to_connect_to_a_Microsoft_Access_database , https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/151989/ , https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/76199/ , https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/145877/